# Combining two Arraylists into one Array

Tags: java

Suppose you have two arrayLists: A and B.

How do I create a new array which is the same size as B and stores the index values of A as integers in sequential order.

So say for example the size of B is 5 and A has 3 values.

```
A[0] = Ra
A[1] = Be
A[2] = Ce


B[0] = F
B[1] = M
B[2] = K
B[3] = P
B[4] = L
```

I want to then create in java different possible versions (say 5 versions) of an arrayC of size 5 (the same size as listB) with a sequential ordering of the indexes of listA.

So like:

```
arrayC[0] = 0
arrayC[1] = 1
arrayC[2] = 1
arrayC[3] = 2
arrayC[4] = 2
```

or

```
arrayC[0] = 0
arrayC[1] = 0
arrayC[2] = 1
arrayC[3] = 2
arrayC[4] = 2
```

are both valid combinations in arrayC. However

```
arrayC[0] = 0
arrayC[1] = 2
arrayC[2] = 1
arrayC[3] = 2
arrayC[4] = 2
```

is not.

Comment: the question is very confusing - you need to clarify in a more exact way (perhaps more examples?) what is it that you want to achieve. I can't make heads or tails from the question!

Comment: Sorry, I thought the examples made it clear. I'll try again, it's quite difficult to explain it.

Comment: So if `listA` is smaller, you want to *randomly* duplicate some values? Is that right? What if `listA` is *larger* than `listB`? And does the actual *content* of `listB` have any significance? Or only its size?

Comment: the sentence "in sequential order, but different combinations." is kind of self-contradictory

Comment: Explaining what you need this for might also help a lot.

Comment: I believe what's being asked here is how to generate all unique combinations of size m from n values. This would make m the size of array B and n the integers in interval 0 to n-1. I'm not certain why this needs to be expressed in terms of two arrays. Or are you using the values of array A rather than its indexes? Will array B always be larger or equal in size as array A?

Comment: @ Joachim Sauer Yes listA is always smaller than list B, the content of listB does not have any significance it is just its size , and yes you're right I want to randomly duplicate some values.

Comment: @Pandy, should `3` really be in `arrayC`? It's not a valid index in list A.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited that out.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but are you trying to implement a genetic algorithm?

Comment: Do you want it balanced? e.g. is 0,0,0,1,1 valid? or 0,0,0,1,2?

Comment: @Jauchim Sauer, no I'm not I may think about it eventually but I'm just doing this now to see what happens.

Comment: @Stephen 0,0,0,1,1 is not valid

Comment: Sorry please say your question clearly, i will try to solve your problem...

Comment: @ Pushpendra Kuntal

Maybe if you tell me what you don't understand exactly I can explain it more clearly?

Comment: @Pandy, please tell me clearly that what should your desired answer,then i will convert it into program.

Comment: Okay, I have two arraylists A and B. I want to create an array that is the same size as B, and the values stored in this new array will be a sequential combination of the indexes in A. So if B is of size 5, and A has 3 index positions then the new array can be 0,0,1,1,2 or 0,1,1,1,2, and I want to output around 4 different combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method returns all orderings. Limit it if you just want a few.

```
public static Set<List<Integer>> orderings(int i, int len, int max) {

    Set<List<Integer>> seqs = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();

    if (len <= 0 || i > max)
        return seqs;

    if (max - i == len) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (i < max)
            l.add(i++);
        seqs.add(l);
        return seqs;
    }

    seqs.addAll(orderings(i    , len - 1, max));
    seqs.addAll(orderings(i + 1, len - 1, max));

    for (List<Integer> l : seqs)
        l.add(0, i);

    return seqs;
}


public static Set<List<Integer>> orderings(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    return orderings(0, arr2.length, arr1.length);
}
```

**Test code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] listA = { 0, 1, 2 };
    int[] listB = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    for (List<Integer> seq : orderings(listA, listB))
        System.out.println(seq);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2]  <-- your second example
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]  <-- your first example
[0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
```

**Ideone.com demo:**
[Link](http://ideone.com/iPLVr)

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    a.add(new Object());
    a.add(new Object());
    a.add(new Object());

    ArrayList b = new ArrayList();
    b.add(new Object());
    b.add(new Object());
    b.add(new Object());
    b.add(new Object());
    b.add(new Object());

    Random r = new Random();
    int c[] = new int[b.size()];
    int aIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <c.length; i++){

        if(i != 0) { //assume we always use aIndex = 0 for first element

            if((c.length - i) < a.size() - aIndex ){ //must increase the index
                aIndex++;
            }
            else if(r.nextBoolean() && aIndex < a.size()-1){ //Randomly increase the index
                aIndex++;
            }
        }
        c[i] = aIndex;
        System.out.print("\nC[" +i +"]:" + aIndex);
    }
```

Comment: ...edited to add in the array list setup. The question specifies ArrayLists into an Array

Comment: you don't need to add anything, just wrap the above code in a Main() or unit test and run it. It will generate a new random valid output each time. cheers Steve

Comment: SAMPLE OUTPUT: C[0]:0
C[1]:0
C[2]:1
C[3]:2
C[4]:2

Answer (score 1):

Alright, assuming I'm understanding the question correctly, here's a program that will print every combination of 5 numbers ranging from 0 to 2. The `getAllCombinations` method is general-purpose, so you can simply alter the values to see different results.

A word of warning: this uses recursion and calculates all results, so it's not very efficient. This is just to get you on your way.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final int sizeA = 3;
        final int sizeB = 5;

        final List<int[]> combos = getAllCombinations(sizeA-1, sizeB);

        int counter = 1;
        for(final int[] combo : combos) {
            System.out.println("Combination " + counter);
            System.out.println("--------------");
            for(final int value : combo) {
                System.out.print(value + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            ++counter;
        }

    }

    private static List<int[]> getAllCombinations(final int maxIndex, final int size) {

        if(maxIndex >= size)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The maximum index must be smaller than the array size.");

        final List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        if(maxIndex == 0) {
            final int[] array = new int[size];
            Arrays.fill(array, maxIndex);
            result.add(array);
            return result;
        }

        //We'll create one array for every time the maxIndex can occur while allowing
        //every other index to appear, then create every variation on that array
        //by having every possible head generated recursively
        for(int i = 1; i < size - maxIndex + 1; ++i) {

            //Generating every possible head for the array
            final List<int[]> heads = getAllCombinations(maxIndex - 1, size - i);

            //Combining every head with the tail
            for(final int[] head : heads) {
                final int[] array = new int[size];
                System.arraycopy(head, 0, array, 0, head.length);
                //Filling the tail of the array with i maxIndex values
                for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
                    array[size - j] = maxIndex;
                result.add(array);
            }

        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you modify this so it calculates a result at random?

Comment: @Pandy One thing you could do is to get the `List` with `getAllCombinations`, then select a bunch of arrays from it at random. Still computes every possible combination, though.